# synchronize HTML5 or JavaScript video to realtime?

Tags: javascript, html5

I will have multiple cellphones playing videos in an art gallery. The video content must be synced to the lights, which are synced to the real-world clock. As in, at 1:00pm the lights go out, 1:15 they turn orange 1:30 they are bright, 1:45 they begin to dim, rinse and repeat every hour. I figured I would point the phones' browsers to web pages (5 different pages in total) and load the video content that way so 1) it's easier than building an app and 2) I can pull date/time data in JS and use that to make sure the video files are playing at the right rate. The videos do not have sound.

I'm wondering what the best way to go about this is. I could break everything into frames and just have the phone cycle through, preloading images as needed, but I would prefer to use a video if possible. I can just render out an hour long video and serve it from the webpage (it's low res, not so big), but I need to make sure it stays on time. I don't mind if it wanders off a little, but that at the 15 minute marks it gets back on track.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Anytime you need to synchronize devices, you want one central controller instructing the devices what to do. This is just as true for mobile phones playing a video as it is the lights. I know one thing for sure: **do not rely on client machine clocks to synchronize anything!**

Instead, the web page should be streaming a video. From the perspective of the mobile device, it would be streaming a live video. The device serving the video is responsible for sending the correct video frames as mobile phones connect and begin playing. This central server should also be responsible for issuing commands to the devices controlling the lights.

You will likely need multiple processes or threads running, which means synchronizing those threads. Now you have one clock to synchronize, and all other devices respond to commands. At that point, you only have latency between: a) server and mobile phone; b) server and lights. This shouldn't be too bad assuming you have a local network, and people are physically close to the wireless router.

Now it's just a simple matter of programming!

Consider searching for multimedia solutions that provide this rather than building your own. This is considerably more difficult than you might think. A fun project, for sure, but much more difficult.

Comment: what is wrong with using the clients' clocks that are automatically synchronized to the cellphone network?

Comment: @user253751: the synchronization is not as close as you might think. People will notice. We take for granted that our cell phones show the same hour and minute, but what you want to do requires sub-second accuracy. You could have several people standing next to each other, and they would notice each other's phones playing slightly different parts of the video, and the lights would be just a hair off. It would ruin the experience.

Answer (score 0):

Greg's answer is sound: use a if you use a streaming video solution such as Icecast, you can guarantee that the server sends the right frames at the right time. There is still a little risk of clients getting behind due to buffering if the connection is not perfect.

If you go the pre-rendered video route, you could have Javascript periodically (e.g. every 15 minutes) poll the server for its current time and then set the playback time (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp) accordingly. But that only has a resolution of one second, so you can't use it for frame-accurate syncing, and setting the time will glitch the video.

Although it sounds like the video is something like a continuous fade to match the lighting? In which case small discontinuities won't matter.

(It feels like there ought to be a real-time "just hand over the frames" solution, maybe involving WebRTC, but I can't immediately find one. If you're not already familiar with ffmpeg, you should learn about it as well)